# Apply completion options dynamically

Tags: docker, fish

I have a [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/) completion like this for `docker`:

```
# 'docker-subcommands.txt' is an exhaustive list derived from the "Usage" message.
set -l subcoms (cat /etc/fish/completions/docker-subcommands.txt)

# Found '__fish_seen_subcommand_from' in the completion for `systemctl`
# (in /usr/share/fish/completions/...).
complete -f -c docker -n "not __fish_seen_subcommand_from $subcoms" -a "$subcoms"

function _docker_container_action
# The placeholder is needed here because fish will choke on an empty completion list.
        echo (docker ps -aq) '{z-placeholder}'
end

function _docker_image_action
        echo (docker images -q) '{z-placeholder}'
end

for sc in cp exec inspect restart rm start stop
        complete -c docker -n "contains $sc (commandline -poc)" -x -a (_docker_container_action)
end

for sc in rmi run
        complete -c docker -n "contains $sc (commandline -poc)" -x -a (_docker_image_action)
end
```

The problem is that the completion for image and container IDs needs to be dynamic (like file completion), whereas the above seems to run the `-a` command when the completion file is (re-)sourced.

How can I make this refresh the options when the completion is actually being applied?

I should mention that I've tried quoting the `-a` command, as seems to be common practice.  But then instead of an option for each ID, I get only one completion option, a long string with space escapes in it (`\`) containing the IDs and `\{z-placeholder}` at the end. :(

---

[...] Quoting the `-a` command does work as long as its output is not produced by `echo` (which stringifies it).  Turns out `-a`'s "choking" problem is not having an argument, which is what happens if you put `docker ps -aq` there directly and there are no container IDs to list.  So this pattern works:

```
function _docker_container_action
    docker ps -aq
end

complete -c docker -n "contains $sc (commandline -poc)" -x -a "(_docker_container_action)"
```

And no need for my placeholder either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> whereas the above seems to run the -a command when the completion file is (re-sourced).

That's because you've included it here as a command substitution, so when the file is `source`d, it expands, and the completion system has no idea what it was before.

But the `-a` option knows to expand its argument at completion-time, so all you need to do is quote it:

```
complete -c docker -n "contains $sc (commandline -poc)" -x -a "(_docker_container_action)"
```

Comment: The problem with that (I tried it earlier, should have edited that in) is that it turns the output into one long string with escapes in it. So if there's one ID put out by `docker ps -aq` my one completion option is, e.g., `25e6809f6fab\ \{z-placeholder\}`.  More IDs, still only one option, longer useless string.

Comment: Make it so you get one thing per-line - in this case that most likely means just ditching the `echo` - `docker ps -aq`, not `echo (docker ps -aq)`. The placeholder isn't necessary because fish *won't* choke on an empty completion, but `-a` does expect an argument.

Comment: Okay, so it the choke happened when I had the echo in the `complete -a` line; I moved it to a function to see if I could work it out there.  Using just plain `docker ps -aq` works, and putting that in a function call means `-a` has an argument regardless of the output.  Cheers :)